# Evenly space out links and centered logo in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm attempting to evenly space out links in a nav bar to the left and right of a centered logo, [similar to this (link).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhGsR.jpg)

[Here is the live website navbar I'd like to ape.](http://arohmade.com)

I've tried a lot of different things, and using flexboxes is as close as I can get it. But it's still not perfect and it doesn't scale down well. My code is totally boneheaded and duct-taped together, but this is what it looks like:

```
.flex-header {
    display: flex;
    height: 100px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-item li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 5px 40px 0 40px;
}


.flex-left { order: 1; }

.flex-right { order: 3; }

.flex-logo { order: 2; }
```

The padding isn't ideal but that's how I have to hack it together to stick. It doesn't hold up in gigantic resolutions either -- the spacing gets all warped. Ideally I'd like to set a percentage width for each list item, but I just can't get it to look right.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please create a working code snippet, including HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encase each navBar section (including the image) in it's own div.

```
<div class="navSection>Section 1</div>
<div class="navSection>Section 2</div>
<div class="navSection>Image</div>
<div class="navSection>Section 4</div>
<div class="navSection>Section 5</div>
```

Then, we'll simply position them and set their widths so that they are all equal.

```
.navSection {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: If this was the answer to your post, please mark it so that it can help others as well.